# When an Eb instrument plays the Concert F scale, what note do they start on?

Tags: theory, scales, instruments, intervals

When an Eb instrument plays the Concert F scale, what note do they start on?
plz help?
I was confused on this question and need more clarification because I play a Concert Bb instrument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you play a Bb instrument, you know that your written C produces the sound of a concert Bb. That is, the instrument sounds one whole step lower than the written pitch. Put another way, the written pitch is a whole step higher than the concert pitch.

Eb instruments are similar. The written C on those instruments produces a concert Eb. Thus, the written note is a minor third lower than the concert pitch -- or the sound is a minor third higher than the instrument's written pitch.

This means that to play a concert F scale, an Eb instrument starts on its written D.

Comment: Technically, the written note is usually a major sixth higher.

Comment: @Richard That's true for woodwinds, but I think the other way for brass. I'll see if I can find something definitive....

Comment: @Richard that depends on the horn.  For example,  the lower clarinets and saxophones may be written a 6th or a 13th up;  the upper soprano ones down a 3rd

Comment: Fair enough; I was assuming, based on the level of the question, only certain instruments.

Answer (score 2):

An Eb-instrument has its name because when you play a written C there comes out a concert Eb. (Similarly your instrument is a Bb-instrument as you get a Bb when playing a written C.)

Now when the sounding Eb is a minor third above C you have to play an A to get a sounding C and analogous to play a D to  get an F.

As Es-instruments are transposing one 4th plus than Bb instruments they have 1 sharp more in their sheet music part. (= plus one 5th). So you can always derive from your sheet music in Bb adding 1 sharp for Eb- instruments.

E.g. concert tone F:

Bass Bb = G => Bass Eb = D (adding one sharp more)

Circle of 5th!