# If a Concert instrument plays an F double sharp scale, what is the first note they play

Tags: theory, scales, intervals

plz help...If a Concert instrument plays an F double sharp scale, what is the first note they play
I was confused on this question and need more clarification because I play a Concert Bb instrument.

Comment: Your question seems really too close to [the one you just posted](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/109583/when-an-eb-instrument-plays-the-concert-f-scale-what-note-do-they-start-on), maybe you should consider editing that question instead of creating a new one, or at least add a comment clarifying what you need if the provided answers are not satisfying.

Comment: What do you mean by "F double sharp scale"? You certainly haven't seen an example in real music.

Comment: This question sounds like a music theory student looking up an answer to an obtuse test question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When an Eb instrument plays the Concert F scale, what note do they start on?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/109583/when-an-eb-instrument-plays-the-concert-f-scale-what-note-do-they-start-on)

Comment: Why would you as a Bb player be confused? We're all confused by the question - where did it come from?

Answer (score 2):

> If a Concert instrument plays an F double sharp scale, what is the first note they play?

A concert instrument should never play such a scale.  No composer should ever write such a scale for any instrument, regardless of transposition.

> I play a Concert Bb instrument.

If you have a written F double sharp scale, then a concert instrument would have a written E sharp scale, which is equally improper.  Conversely, if you are looking at an F double sharp scale written for a concert-pitch instrument, and you want to play it on your B-flat instrument, you would play a G double sharp scale.

All of these are pure insanity.  Instead, they should be written as F, G, or A scales.

Unless the composer (or arranger) of the piece you're playing is sadistic, or trying to make some sort of intellectual point, you should also consider the possibility that you have misunderstood the composer's intentions.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, whilst there might be an Fx scale, it's extremely unusual  for it to be used anywhere. Fx is enharmonic in most cases, certainly in 12tet to G♮, so that scale and its notes would be preferrable.

But, in answer to the actual question, the first note would have to be , as is the case in any scale, the root or tonic note. Here Fx. It may well sound like G, but the note will be Fx.

Comment: "it's extremely unusual for it to be used anywhere": that's a mild way of looking at it.  I would say "it's an error for it to be used anywhere."

Comment: It **may** be used in a piece starting in key F# that has a keychange up a semitone - if anyone would be daft enough to write like that...

Answer (score 0):

The F## Major scale is: F## G## A## B♯ C## D## E##

It is considered a theoretical scale, so it would surprise me if you were playing in the key of F## Major.